# Clearer explanation on why questions are deemed off-topic?

Tags: discussion, support

Given my situation I am sorry that I ask so many off-topic questions on Stack Exchange sites. Please advise me as to where I can find clear documentation of what questions are deemed on-topic for each of the appropriate sites?

I was under the impression that the following question was on-topic having seen similar questions in the same area (Server Fault) when Googling as [my closed question](https://serverfault.com/questions/442929/accessing-my-xampp-services-from-wan#comment479133_442929)

Further, is it not better to move questions to the appropriate area so that others (and myself) can see where such questions belong? Please also state if this is the correct area to ask this type of question.

The comment on my question was not constructive either as clearly my question was server and network related.

Comment: I do not remember where to find the guides for each of these sites.

Comment: The site-specific FAQ is linked at the top of each and every site within the network. If that fails to clarify anything, why not ask on the site's Meta whether or not your question might be a good fit.

Comment: @Bart Where is each sitw's meta? I have been advised by you before,, but I need an example if you can?

Comment: Once again, at the top of each site within the network, there is a Meta link. Click it and it will take you to the Meta specifically for that site. With respect to the question asked on Server Fault, I assume that the "in a professional environment" is of key importance and why your question is off-topic.

Comment: @Bart Thank you so much again. I am still convinced the link question was on Topi though.

Comment: Feel free to ask for clarification on Server Fault's Meta. http://meta.serverfault.com/

Comment: @thejartender: please re-read the serverfault FAQ (http://serverfault.com/faq): "**anything in a home setting**" is there, in bold, in the "what's **not** on topic" part. Your question says "I'm trying to set up a home server".

Comment: @Mat I did not mean I home server as in one to toy around with or for home usage. I am looking at setting up a proper server to host several production sites, but before I do this I am practicing if this can be done with an old computer (at home) before buying a server.

Comment: @thejartender: that's not the point. You're not setting up a server in a professional hosting facility. You're in a home setting/environment.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is about setting up software development tools on a client operating system in a home environment. This makes it off topic for serverfault. From the [What kind of questions can I ask here?](https://serverfault.com/faq#questions) our FAQ

> and it is not about…
>
> **Anything in a home setting**

I thought that the comment I left was quite constructive. It tells you why your question is off topic and it also points you to where is may be on topic.

Comment: @lain This existing question lead me to ask it there... http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&ved=0CEgQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fserverfault.com%2Fquestions%2F442929%2Faccessing-my-xampp-services-from-wan&ei=fPOLULqWN4Sk4gT8vYDADA&usg=AFQjCNFAt6ekcqH6maHrSwZKKJciXX4J6w&sig2=vc7IHIICEZjhMKkhNNlaIw

Comment: @thejartender: that's a link to your closed question

Comment: @Bart: read the comment I left on the original question

Comment: @Bart: for this particular question perhaps not but WAMP/XAMPP and similar development environment questions really aren't SF and they are developer tools.

Comment: @lain Sorry I meant this (and many others as I keep landing up on server fault postings) http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&ved=0CE4QFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Fserverfault.com%2Fquestions%2F209150%2Fhow-to-access-localhost-from-by-ip-address&ei=0_WLUM-SIvKM4gSj4IHYCA&usg=AFQjCNHNPKLHLJZScZpA5Xq98tTjbBIzkA&sig2=zmopiR2SRJ7gU_08bzU8sQ Even though this one is closed too. Many aren't

Comment: @thejartender And that question is closed as....off-topic.

Comment: @Bart: You're right - I'll fix that and open a dev tools discussion at a later date.

Comment: @Bart Thank you so much for pointing out the "faq" and "meta" options.